# Google Maps jQuery draw distance from point A to point B using string City/County names

Tags: jquery, google-maps, draw, distance

I must implement a map with a start point A and an end point B using google maps. In my data base I'm storing Region/County string names and not geolocation data (longtitude and latitude). Is possible to draw the line between these two point using only String Region/County names? Am I need to update my data base with all Geolocation for each Region/County?

What plugin should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to get the latitude/longitude from somewhere.  Now, you might be able to get the lat/long at execution time by making use of the Google Maps Geocoder API
   https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/

If you don't have that many points, however, it might make sense to geocode all your points and store it in the database: it will be speedier at execution time.